# Invalid Time Literal in Teradata Dynamic SQL

Tags: teradata

The following stored procedure works fine when I use static sql to insert values into the DBCMNGR.ALERTREQUEST but does not work when trying to use the dynamic sql string.

I get invalid date literal and time literal when trying to call the below stored procedure.

```
CALL TESTDB.ALERT_REQUEST_INSERT('Test_JobName','Test_JobDescription',
'Test_ActionDestination','Test_JobFullMessage')
```

Need help to actually work this without any errors.

In the DBCMNGR.ALERTREQUEST the DATE and time are defined as follows:

```
ReqDate DATE FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD'
ReqTime INTEGER
```

---

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTDB.ALERT_REQUEST_INSERT( IN p_JobName CHARACTER(60), IN p_JobDescription CHARACTER(120), IN p_ActionDestination CHARACTER(120), IN p_JobFullMessage CHARACTER(600) ) ) 
BEGIN 
SET SQLSTR = 'INSERT INTO DBCMNGR.ALERTREQUEST ' || '(AlertRequest.ReqDate ' || ',AlertRequest.ReqTime ' || ',AlertRequest.JobName ' || ',AlertRequest.Description ' || ',AlertRequest.EventValue ' || ',AlertRequest.ActionCode ' || ',AlertRequest.RepeatPeriod ' || ',AlertRequest.Destination ' || ',AlertRequest.Message ' || ') ' || 'VALUES ( ' || ' DATE ' || ',TIME  ' || ''',''' || TRIM(p_JobName) || ''',''' || TRIM(p_JobDescription) || ''',0 ' || ',''+'' ' || ',0 ' || ''',''' || TRIM(p_ActionDestination) || ',''' || TRIM(p_JobFullMessage) || ''');'; 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTR; END;
```

Comment: When I call the above stored procedure with the mentioned parameters below, I get the invalid time and date literal errors and I am struggling to resolve the issue.
 
CALL TESTDB.ALERT_REQUEST_INSERT('Test_JobName','Test_JobDescription', 'Test_ActionDestination','Test_JobFullMessage')

Comment: Your ReqTime column an integer.  The Time function doesn't return an integer, it returns a timestamp.